# Get The Post Type A Taxonomy Is Attached To

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Being given a taxonomy or term, is is possible to pull any / all post types the taxonomy is attached to?

For example, knowing the built in taxonomy `category` or being given a term in the `category` taxonomy, is there a function to reverse engineer that `category` is a taxonomy of `post` ?

**Unneeded Info**

I'm working with some custom fields in taxonomy terms that specifically need to know the post type, but if the post type parameter in the URL isn't there for whatever reason I run into trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we peek into the global `$wp_taxonomies` variable we see the associated object types.

There might be better ways to do this or even core functions, but you could try the following:

```
function wpse_172645_get_post_types_by_taxonomy( $tax = 'category' )
{
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    return ( isset( $wp_taxonomies[$tax] ) ) ? $wp_taxonomies[$tax]->object_type : array();
}
```

then for the default setup you get:

```
$out = wpse_172645_get_post_types_by_taxonomy( 'category' );
print_r( $out );
```

with the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => post
)
```

Answer (score 14):

There is no need to use the `$wp_taxonomies` global variable directly as WordPress has the [`get_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/) function to access taxonomies in it ( in core since version 2.3.0). Since WordPress 4.7.0 the return type is a [`WP_Taxonomy`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_taxonomy/) object with the property `$object_type`

```
$taxonomy = get_taxonomy( 'category' );
print_r( $taxonomy->object_type );
```

Comment: Prefer this way. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can do the reverse with [`get_object_taxonomies`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies). Combine it with [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) to iterate over post types to check the taxonomies registered for each.

**EDIT**- Here's an example that produces the same output as @birgire's function, without using dirty globals.

```
function wpse_172645_get_post_types_by_taxonomy( $tax = 'category' ){
    $out = array();
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );
        if( in_array( $tax, $taxonomies ) ){
            $out[] = $post_type;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```